# How to send emails in Bash with a for loop?

Tags: bash

I have three arrays of the same size: `outputs` as the body of the email, `job_id`, which is used in the subject, and `email` with a list of emails.

However, I'm getting an error when I run my script:

> email: FATAL: Smtp error: 555 5.5.2 Syntax error.

Is there a way to reference array elements for the email parameter? This code works when I put an actual email, not `"${email[$i]}"`

```
for (( i=1;i<${#outputs[@]};i++ )); do
    echo "${outputs[$i]}" | email -s "Job #${job_id[$i]} completed" "${email[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: Put `set -x` before the loop, so you can see what bash thinks it's doing.